# How to get list from a delayed variable in for loop in bat file?

Tags: batch-file

This is my code:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a in ("%my_path%") do (
    set z=%%a
    for %%A in (!z:.= !) do (
        echo %%A
    )
)
```

In the second loop I need to get list from `!z:.= !`. But it doesn't work. However, if I do this way:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a in ("%my_path%") do (
    set z=%%a
    for %%A in ("!z:.= !") do (
        echo %%A
    )
)
```

Then it works, but I have two extra `"` in output which I don't need. Could anyone say how to get list from `!z:.= !` in a correct way (without getting extra quotes)?

EDIT: In pseudo code in the second loop I need:

```
string[] splits = z.split(".");
for (var split : splits) {
     echo split
}
```

Comment: If you look at the output of `for /?`, there's a bit on page 5 about how `%%~A` can be used to strip the quotes from `%%A`.

Comment: @SomethingDark No, I just need to use the solution which you have given me earlier in the second loop. As I wrote I need `pure` splits.

Comment: Just use `for %%A in ("!z:.=" "!") do echo %%~A`

Comment: @Aacini I need to get every split (%%A) separately, so, in my example, every split must be printed on new line.

Comment: This is exactly what my example do. Did you tested it? Perhaps if you show us your input and your desired output we can't need to guess anymore...

Comment: @Aacini Yes, I tested your solution, but I get one string without delimiter. Please, see my edit.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any input/output example in your edit... If you want the contents of `!z!` with each point converted into space, just use: `echo !z:.= !` instead of your second  `for %%A ...`

Comment: @Aacini Thank you for your help. Let me explain this way. I have `z` variable. I need to split it by `.` and iterate every split (I need them for future processing). This is all I need. Could you say how to do it?

Comment: You can do that as I said before: `for %%A in ("!z:.=" "!") do echo %%~A` If this don't solve your problem, please show us what you get from this code and what you want... **`:(`**

Comment: @Aacini Yes, you are right. My fault. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: As an alternative: `for %%A in (!z:.^=^ !) do echo %%A`

Comment: Sorry, but _now_ I want to know what happened... 25 minutes ago I show you a code and asked you: "Did you tested it?". Your answer was: "Yes, I tested your solution", but _that_ was not what you wanted... What changed now?

Comment: @Aacini I didn't notice that you changed `("!z:.= !")` to `("!z:.=" "!")`. My fault.